# Не могу установить unity editor, а при установке через unity arhive не может сбилдеться

Tags: unity3d-android

При установки unity editor происходит ошибка : " **Editor application
Install failed: Validation Failed** "

Если я скачиваю через unity archive, то при билде происходит ошибка (я делаю приложения на android и я установил требуемые дополнения) : " **Каталог Java Development Kit (jdk) не задан или недействителен. Пожалуйста, исправьте это в Edit Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools.** ".

Comment: Вы задали путь до jdk в External Tools?

Comment: нет я не пытался этого сделать